# How to capture network traffic using selenium webdriver in python without using HAR

Tags: python, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium webdriver and is not able to capture network traffic.
I tried using performance timing https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceTiming/fetchStart but getting the same timings every time I call the same web page through automation which is different when comparing it while doing it manually.
I have a website wherein I need to capture the network timings for different dropdown but getting the same result when using performance timing.
Usage of HAR export trigger is avoided as it always gives some error or compatibility problems in Firefox.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to get the changed source of a webpage once you perform an activity over it. If so this should resolve your issue. 'driver.page_source'